# Executing Oracle package procedure from SQL Server via linked server returns result with wrong encoding

Tags: sql-server, oracle, package, linked-server

I have an Oracle server that has a package with a procedure like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST AS
     PROCEDURE name (id IN NUMBER, name OUT VARCHAR2);
END TEST
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST AS
    PROCEDURE name (id IN NUMBER, name OUT VARCHAR2) IS
    BEGIN
        SELECT NAME as name
        INTO name
        FROM NAMES
        WHERE ID = id;
    END name;
END TEST;
```

I cannot modify the Oracle server in any way.

And I have a SQL Server connected to the Oracle server via linked server (provider is 'Oracle Provider for OLE DB' if that's important).

I'm trying to get the results of the procedure 'name' inside SQL Server like so:

```
DECLARE @id int = 117, @name nvarchar(200)
EXEC ('begin TEST.name(?,?); END;', @id, @name OUTPUT) AT OrclDB
SELECT @name
```

Some names contain Lithuanian letters (i.e. **ą č ę ė į š ų ū ž**) and for some reason letters **š** and **ž** are returned properly, but letters **ą č ę ė į ų ū** are instead changed to: **a c e e i u u**.

If I select the name directly from the table using OpenQuery I get the correct result

```
SELECT * 
FROM OpenQuery(OrclDB, 'SELECT NAME from NAMES WHERE ID = 117')
```

Is there a way to get the correct result from the package procedure?

The package procedure return the names correctly if ran directly in the oracle server.

The problem only occurs when trying to access the procedure from SQL Server.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to, but does `N'begin TEST.name(?,?); END;'` make a difference?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning No. Still get the same result.